# superstore data analysis projects

Tags: visualization

where can I find good projects on retail/superstore data analysis and visualization? I am trying to see the scheme and how to go about it, as well as the different visualisation techniques used? Preferably in R.

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/12/superstore-retail-analysis/